# Why do TimeStamp and KronosTimeZone list different time zone offsets?

Tags: xml, timezone-offset, kronos-workforce-central

I have a Kronos Workforce Central 8.1 server located in an EST time zone. To confirm that the time zone was configured properly, I sent a `GetServerTime` request to the server.

```xml
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Object="ServerTime" Action="GetServerTime"/>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

To my surprise, the server response listed two different timezone offsets for GMT.

- TimeStamp="5/09/2018 10:23AM **GMT-04:00**"
- KronosTimeZone="(**GMT -05:00**) Eastern Time"

```xml
<Kronos_WFC TimeStamp="5/09/2018 10:23AM GMT-04:00" version="1.0" WFCVersion="8.1.1.569">
    <Response Status="Success" Action="GetServerTime" Object="ServerTime">
        <ServerTime DateTime="5/09/2018 10:23AM" KronosTimeZone="(GMT -05:00) Eastern Time"/>
    </Response>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

Why is Workforce Central returning different GMT offsets for `TimeStamp` and `KronosTimeZone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The 1 hour difference in GMT offset is caused by Daylight Savings Time.**

> The DST period in the United States begins each year on the 2nd Sunday in March, when clocks are set forward by 1 hour. They are turned back again to standard time on the 1st Sunday in November as DST ends.
>
> <sub>[timeanddate.com - Daylight Savings Time in the USA](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/daylight-saving-usa.html)</sub>

In other words:

- `KronosTimeZone` is the server's **time zone**, which for EST will always be `GMT -05:00`.
- `TimeStamp` is the server's **current time**, which is `GMT -04:00` due to daylight savings.

The TimeStamp offset will revert back to `GMT -05:00` in November when DST ends.